# How to get utf-8 accent code from an accented character?

Tags: c, character-encoding, special-characters, non-ascii-characters, codepages

I'm working on a program in C, I need to be able to get the code of a character, but in the case of an accented character like "á", it must return the code of the character "a" and the accent (´).

```
in:
á
out:
"á"=C3 A1
"a"=61
"´"=C2 B4
```

Is there a way to get the accent?
This should work for any type of combining characters (acute, grave, diaeresis, circumflex ...)

In some projects I have used iconv to convert between encodings, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Or is it possible with iconv to do that?
Something like

```
in: cómo estás, niño?
out c´omo est´as, ni~no?
```

Comment: You're asking for the "Normalization Form D (NFD)" of the input. Beyond that, this becomes a library recommendation question, which is off-topic.

Comment: Agree. This is a very generic question. Have you tried any lib so far? If so, then you can pose a more specific question.

Comment: Here you can get information about a character https://unicodelookup.com, might help as inspiration for your C library.